# Law of ZY is not equal to Law of XY

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

This is rather a basic problem on the distribution on the product of Random Variables. I've tried proved by definiton of distribution and even with convolution. But i get stucked. Any hint?

If $X$ and $Y$ have the same law, $Z$ is a random variable, then $XZ$ and $ZY$ have te same law?

Comment: What if say $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but $Z=X$?

Comment: I've tried to state by definition of distribution that it's$P\left (  w \in \Omega \mid X\left ( \omega  \right )\in B\right )= P\left ( w\in \Omega \mid Y\left ( \omega  \right ) \in B\right )$ and tried to combine with the definition on Z, $P\left ( w\in \Omega \mid Z\left ( \omega  \right ) \in B\right )$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ has any symmetric distribution and $Y=-X$ then $X$ and $Y$ have the same law. IF we take $Z=X$ then $XZ=X^{2}$ is a non-negative random variable  whereas $ZY=-X^{2}$ is a non-positive random variable. This gives any number of counterexamples.